# finding the last occurrence of a string and replacing it

Tags: php

I have the following link as a string in php:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/10.jpg';
```

I am trying to add the word BIG before the number so at the end I will have:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/big10.jpg';
```

I am currently accomplishing that by using explode on `/` then adding big to the last array. My only issue is that in the future, this link might have less `/` i.e.: `http://www.example.com/assets/10.jpg`. In this case, my explode statement will not work. Is there a better way to add the word big after the last occurance of `/`?

I also came up with this method:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/10.jpg';
$filename = substr(strrchr($url, "/"), 1); // returns 10.jpg
$newfilename = 'big'.substr(strrchr($url, "/"), 1); // returns big10.jpg
$newurl = str_replace($filename,$newfilename,$url); // replaces 10.jpg with big.jpg
```

Comment: The code seems fine. I tested it as well. No worries about changing number of '/' to explode on, as you always choose the last / in your code which always will be last no matter how many '/''s there will be.

Comment: Your code looks bloated tho. There are simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`Explode` will always work. However, if you want a neater way to do it you can do this:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/10.jpg';
$newurl = substr_replace($url, "big", strrpos($url, '/') + 1, 0);
```

This will give your expected result: `http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/big10.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned into above question as a solution to it please try executing following code snippet .

```
  <?php
$url         = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/10.jpg';
$fileName    = basename($url);
$newFileName = 'big' . $fileName;
$url         = str_ireplace($fileName, $newFileName, $url);
echo $url;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few methods to accomplish what you're wanting.

To me the easiest would be to use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to extract the filename, and then append your prefix to the `basename`.

```
$prefix = 'big';
$url = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/10.jpg';
$pathinfo = pathinfo($url);
var_dump($pathinfo['dirname'] . '/' . $prefix . $pathinfo['basename']);
```

Result: https://3v4l.org/3MkIG

```
string(51) "http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/big10.jpg"
```

Object oriented approach: https://3v4l.org/aF5lf

```
class FileNamePrefixer extends SplFileInfo
{
    public function addPrefix($prefix)
    {
        return $this->getPathInfo() . '/' .  $prefix . $this->getBaseName();
    }
}
```

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/10.jpg';
$fileInfo = new FileNamePrefixer($url);
var_dump($fileInfo->addPrefix('big'));
```

---

Another method is to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to specify a pattern of words you want to replace.

```
$prefix = 'big';
$url = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/10.jpg';
$new_url = preg_replace('/([\w|\s|-]+)(\.\w+)$/', $prefix . '$1$2', $url);
var_dump($new_url);
```

The pattern `([\w|\s|-]+)(\.\w+)$` means; at the end of the string, look for a word *(characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, space, and -)*, followed by a period, which is followed by another word and store them in variables `$1` and `$2`.

Result: https://3v4l.org/6e8d7

```
string(51) "http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/big10.jpg"
```

Note that if your URL will optionally contain fragments or a querystring, the `preg_replace` pattern above will not work. Instead you would need to account for them as optional like so:

```
$prefix = 'big';
$url = 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/10.jpg?foo=bar&baz=foo#foobar';
$new_url = preg_replace('/([\w|\s|-]+)(\.\w+)(\?.+)?(#.+)?$/', $prefix . '$1$2$3$4', $url);
var_dump($new_url);
```

The pattern `(\?.+)?(#.+)?` means; optionally find ? followed by anything, and optionally find # followed by anything and store them in variables `$3` and `$4` with the original pattern.

Result: https://3v4l.org/uuYrO

```
string(74) "http://www.example.com/assets/images/temp/big10.jpg?foo=bar&baz=foo#foobar"
```